# Q: input to objects in a matrix?

Tags: c++

I have a homemade class (ComplexNumber) which has a constructor which takes in two arguments, the imaginary part and the real part. As such

```
ComplexNumber z(4,3);
```

which can output

```
(4 + 3i)
```

In my code i'm trying to allocate an empty object matrix and hereafter assigning values. It is possible to assign the z in the example, but i cannot assign two inputs two the A[][]. Anyone who can help?

```
#include "ComplexNumber.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


ComplexNumber** Allocate_object_matrix(int ARows, int ACols);

void output_matrix(ComplexNumber **A, int ARows, int ACols);
    
int main()
{
    int ARows=3;
    int ACols=3;
    int n=3;
    
    ComplexNumber **A = Allocate_object_matrix(ARows,ACols);
    
    ComplexNumber z1(4,3);
    A[2][0](4,3); //this does not work

    std::cout << z1 << A[2][0] << std::endl;
    output_matrix(A,ARows,ACols);
}



ComplexNumber** Allocate_object_matrix(int ARows, int ACols)
{

    ComplexNumber** A;
    A = new ComplexNumber* [ARows];
    for (int i=0;i<ARows;i++){
        A[i] = new ComplexNumber [ACols];
    }
    
    return A;
}

void output_matrix(ComplexNumber **A,int ARows, int ACols)
{
    std::cout << "The matrix is: " << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<ARows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ACols;j++){
           std::cout << A[i][j] << "\t";
            
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

This is the constructor for the class, forgot to add to the first Q

```
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double x, double y)
{
    mRealPart = x;
    mImaginaryPart = y;
}
```

Comment: It should be: `A[2][0] = z;`

Comment: `A[2][0] = {4,3};` should work, though you better include how you defined `ComplexNumber`

Comment: anyway this code is crippled style of mixed C and C++ with memory leak. It is way better to use `std::vector` to achieve same result.

Comment: Hmm, A[2][0] = {4,3}; does not work, it return error: expected expression

Comment: Maybe you're using some old standard of C++ language. Perhaps you'd need to overload `operator=` and then `A[2][0] = ComplexNumber(4,3);`.

Comment: Which version of compiler do you use? Do you have C++11 enabled?